# Mouse meta-globin mRNA problem

Tags: molecular-biology, homework, rna

> This is an mRNA strand of mouse meta-globin:
>
> 5'-ccccagauacggaauucgaau-3'
>
> A) Which small RNA (below) is most likely to regulate expression of
>   meta-globin?
>
> 1. 5'-auucgaauuuucuaucugggg-3'
> 2. 5'-ggggucuaucuuuuaagcuua-3'
> 3. 5'-ccccagauacggaauucgaau-3'
> 4. 5'-uaagcuuaaggcauagacccc-3'
>
> B) This RNA most likely?
>
> 1. acts as an siRNA
> 2. inhibit meta-globin translation
> 3. increase meta-globin translation
> 4. help transport meta-globin mRNA back into the nucleus

My attempt:

I think A is 2 because the strand is complementary and will bind nicely to the mRNA strand.  For B, I'm between 2 and 3, but cant decide.

Comment: I'm going with 1) for A since you need the strand to be the *reverse complement*.

Comment: A) Is this a take-home exam question? 1) Yes, then I can't answer your questions for you. 2) No, well, I'll see if I have time tomorrow to get to it.

Comment: @Larry_Parnell this is a problem I found in an MCAT book.  (I'm studying for the mcat)

Answer (score 1):

There are always exceptions but you can consider some general rules.

A is 1 i.e the sequence that is perfectly complementary (2 is complementary but direction is parallel — cannot base-pair), then B would be 1 (siRNA). Reasons (some are just based on general rules of siRNA design):

- siRNAs have to be perfectly complementary
- The size is also perfect for a siRNA (21nt)
- U/A (2-3 residues) at the 5' of the siRNA
- U at 10th position
- GC content 43% (ideal 30-50%)

See [here](http://www.lifetechnologies.com/in/en/home/references/ambion-tech-support/rnai-sirna/general-articles/-sirna-design-guidelines.html) for guidelines for siRNA design.